# Form submission on pressing enter button

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms, dom-events, struts

I am handling ajax suggestions using keyboard and mouse, it is capturing every keyevent except <kbd>enter</kbd> key(13). What I want is to get the "selected suggestion value" into the text box. For this I am handling `keyevent = 13`. Now the problem is when I am pressing <kbd>enter</kbd> key, my form get submitted instead of going into the "if block" where I am checking (`keyevent = 13`).

I am using struts `<html:submit>` tag to submit my form. I guess, the browser automatically set the focus into first `<html:submit>` tag that comes in its place. How to defocus this? I tried setting focus at other fields but trick doesn't work.

The other way is, I can use simple `<html:button>` and can get the things working, but the system already using `<html:submit>`. So, getting approval and modification is quite hectic.

Code for submit button:

```
<html:submit styleClass="btn" property="method.saveVisaRequestForRMG" onclick="bCancel=false" styleId="submitBtn">
```

and code for event handling:

```
// Handle ENTER key 
case 13: handleSelectedItem(obj, container, cur);
     ev.cancelBubble = true;
     break;
```

How to come out of this problem? Please suggest me.

Comment: Can you add a sample of your code? From what I've understood, you basically need to prevent the form from submitting when clicking on "Enter". This can be achieved by using `event.preventDefault();` https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.preventDefault

Comment: Code for submit button: <html:submit styleClass="btn" property="method.saveVisaRequestForRMG"  onclick="bCancel=false" 
     styleId="submitBtn"> and code for event handling:  // Handle ENTER key
  case 13:
   handleSelectedItem(obj, container, cur);
   ev.cancelBubble = true;
   break;

Answer (score 2):

If you use jquery there is a simple way to handle enter press events:

```
  $(window).keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 13) {
      e.preventDefault();
      alert('Enter!');
    }
  });
```

After you prevented the default event you can do whatever you want for example posting the data into the server, saying hello or whatever :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to `return false;` to cancel the event handling of the submit?

Comment: can you please more elaborate where i should return this

Comment: Sorry, didn't see your code when I posted this answer - if you return false from the onsubmit method, the submit gets canceled. I'm not sure about struts, but you can try to return false from your `method.saveVisaRequestForRMG`.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have something like:

```
onsubmit="return formValidator()"
```

Comment: i didn't seen this but it should be there